# How can you specify the "Selected" value for a Cascading DropdownlistFor with ViewModel?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

The example that I'm looking at is https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Cascading-Dependent-DropDownList-in-ASPNet-MVC.aspx

The example works well. But cannot see how to specify a selected value before passing the model to the view.

You can specify the "Selected" value by
`model.Countries.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = country.CountryName, Value = country.CountryId.ToString(), Selected = true });`

The Viewmodel results shows the specified item with the Selected = true.

But the dropdown in the view `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CountryId, Model.Countries, "Please select", new { onchange = "document.forms[0].submit();" })` just ignores it.

Can anyone see a work around to get the selected value to be displayed?

Comment: Works in MVC v5, what version of MVC are you using?

Comment: Same version.  That's odd.  Should work for each of the three drop downs as well.

Comment: `@{
    var id = 0;
    var items = new SelectListItem[]
    {
        new SelectListItem() { Text = "First", Value = "1" },
        new SelectListItem() { Text = "Second", Value = "2", Selected = true }
    };

    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => id, items, "Please Select", new { onclick = "console.log('select list clicked!');" });
}`  this is the quick test i did on my end.  Only difference i noticed was array vs. list, which doesn't matter since the method accepts IEnumerable<SelectListItem>

Comment: Your example works as expected. But when I try and select the value via the Viewmodel, it doesn't work.  The way I'm trying it is to have a text box that allows me to specify a criteria and that sets the first drop down and in tern sets the cascading drop down.   This appears to be all working according to the controller when i step through it. Hmm..

Comment: set a breakpoint on the `@DropDownListFor` line in the view and inspect the `Model.Countries` collection.

Comment: Checked the Model and the selected record does have the "selected = true" set. But it still doesn't respond to it.

Comment: @hijinxbassist ,Been doing some research and came across this "setting the Selected property in your code is ignored. The only time its respected is when you do not bind to a model property". So basically when the `dropdownlistfor` is bound to a model, it ignores the "selected" value.   It seems that setting the id value in the model that is bound to the `dropdownlistfor` is supposed to act like the "selected". But what I'm seeing is the id has a value of 1 (for example), but then in the view, it's changes to a zero.   hmm.

Comment: Wow that is a shame it no longer works as expected.  I tested a bunch of different ways and you are correct that selected is not honored.  I feel like this used to work as expected in previous versions.

Comment: Do you  know of any way to know when a dropdownlistfor binds?  Trying to think of a way to work around this change from the clients side, say javascript.  I know the alternative is ViewBag, not a big fan of that approach.

Comment: Yeah its pretty easy to set the selected option using JQuery.  
`<script>
        function setSelectedOption(selector, selectedVal) {
            $(selector).val(selectedVal);
        }
        setSelectedOption('#CountryId', "3");
    </script>`

Comment: thank you.. With a slight tweak, I got it working...